# jscrollpane track goes past the DIV border if DIV is under jQuery-ui tab

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, jscrollpane

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {              
        // Init tabs. If following line is commented, scroll pane looks fine
        $("#tabs").tabs();

        // init jscrollpane
        $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();        
});

</script>
```

[jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nishant80/zRVqB/)

As you can see in result, the vertical scroll-bar sticks out towards top and horizontal bar sticks out towards left. This makes it look ugly.

I would like them to be exactly aligned with the table.

If I remove tabs, they won't stick out. So I guess it has something to do with how jscrollpane is behaving under jQuery-ui tab.

I thought I will request jscrollpane and jQuery-ui developers to look into it after checking with the fantastic SO community.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This must be one of those rare questions on SO that go un-answered/un-commented for days!

I contacted the jscrollpane author and he says that it has nothing to do with jscrollpane. Please refer to this link for a workaround (suggested by the author):
https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/issues/250#issuecomment-24308250